# The entity type Interests is not part of the model for the current context

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to bypass use the same model that I was using in entity framework with Dbcontext / Dbset

Reason was that i'm trying to get into automapper , but before that, I figured that since my main core properties are there , that I should be able to use a business poco instead of the data access poco

```
IGenericRepository<Data.BusinessEntities.Interests> interestRepository = null;
interestRepository = new GenericRepository<Interests>();
var interest = interestRepository.SelectAll().ToList();
```

And this blows up

`An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code`

`Additional information: The entity type Interests is not part of the model for the current context.`

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    //private GenericRepoContext db = null;
    private readonly InternTrackingDbContext db;
    private DbSet<T> table = null;

    public GenericRepository()
    {
        //this.db = new GenericRepoContext();
        this.db = new InternTrackingDbContext();
        table = db.Set<T>();
    }

    //public GenericRepository(GenericRepoContext db)
    public GenericRepository(InternTrackingDbContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;
        table = db.Set<T>();
    } 

    public IEnumerable<T> SelectAll()
    {
        return table.ToList();
    }

 //....
}
```

Comment: Looks like `Interests` is not part of Entity Framework object model mapping. You can't just use `Set<T>()` on *any* T, but only on those types that are part of the object model mapping

Comment: If you have configured EF and AutoMapper correctly, what you can do is to have a `GenericRepository<TEntity>` that has a `SelectAll<TProjection>()` method, and use automapper's `ProjectTo` extension to do the mapping internally

Comment: Is there a good example that you recommend , cause I really don't like my GenericRepository , and the automapper mappings I think are not that great

Comment: If you don't want to use AutoMapper with [ProjectTo](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions), you have to roll your own mapping/projection engine. I do have an example on that, but I think it's a bit out of scope for the question